# position of UIPopoverController in iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I have opened a pop up window on button click.

I want to set x and y position of that view.  I have tried a lot but can't set it properly.

This is my code:

```
-(IBAction)product2_click_h2
{
    //build our custom popover view
    UIViewController* popoverContent2 = [[UIViewController alloc]
                                         init];

    UIView* popoverView2 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,100,200,200)];

    popoverView2.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    UITextView *prod2_info = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,5,390,290)];
    [prod2_info setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:15]];
    [popoverView2 addSubview:prod2_info];
    [prod2_info setEditable:NO];
    prod2_info.text = @"\n"
    "                    Higher Mileage Motor Oil :\n "
    "                --------------------------------------\n\n"
    "  -->  MaxLife NextGen Higher Mileage Motor Oil  \n\n" 
    "- Special seal conditioners rejuvenate seals\n"
    "   within the engine block to help \n"
    "   prevent oil leaks that lead to sludge and deposits.\n"
    "- Anti-oxidant additives reduce oil viscosity breakdown\n"
    "  to help prevent engine clogging sludge and deposit formation. \n"
    "- Detergents chemically bond with and remove existing\n"
    "  sludge and deposits\n"
    "- Additional friction-reducing additives help reduce abrasion within engine\n"
    "- Anti-wear agents help prevent engine damage \n"
    "- Available in the following viscosity grades \n"
    "    - 5W-30     \n "
    "   - 10W-30    \n ";
    prod2_info.scrollEnabled =YES;
    popoverContent2.view = popoverView2;
    popoverContent2.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(400,300);

    //create a popover controller
    self.popovercontroller_2 = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                                initWithContentViewController:popoverContent2];

    //present the popover view non-modal with a
    //refrence to the button pressed within the current view
    [self.popovercontroller_2 presentPopoverFromRect:product2.frame
                                              inView:self.view
                            permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                            animated:YES];

}
```

Here's what it looks like right now:

[image]

Comment: You're welcome.  Title says "size" but it sounds like you want to control the position, right?  What exactly is `product2` and where is it in the view?

Comment: yes right..product 2 in button name...here i have set images on buttons and on button click , i want to open pop up window...but i cant set the position. so when i click on image..pop up should be open near by that image(button)

Comment: Do you have a separate button for each product?  Do all the buttons call this method?  If so, how can `product2` be pointing to the button that was clicked?

Comment: i have diff buttons . .for product1...button is product1,,,for  second product..m having button named product2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of this:

```
[self.popovercontroller_2 presentPopoverFromRect:product2.frame
                                          inView:self.view
                        permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                        animated:YES];
```

just make change like this:

```
[self.popovercontroller_2 presentPopoverFromRect:product2.frame
                                          inView:**button.bounds**
                        permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                        animated:YES];
```

Comment: write only ur button name or try "yourButtonName.bound"

Comment: [self.popovercontroller_2 presentPopoverFromRect:product2.frame
                                          inView:product2.bounds
                        permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                        animated:YES];