# How the prevent the popover from hiding with status bar in iOS6

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller

I have a popover, which is presented from the code:

```
    CGPoint screenPoint = [self.mapView screenPoint: self.selectedObject.pointCoordinate];
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(screenPoint.x, screenPoint.y, 1, 1);
    [self.detailViewPopover presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

As u can see on the screenshot - the popover is hiding by the status bar - is it possible the exclude the status bar frame from the area where popover should be displayed?

The content size for view in popover looks like this:

```
self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake (320, self.view.frame.size.height - 100);
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You reset the UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp to UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny

```
  [self.listViewPopover presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Comment: oh, sorry, please see the edited question  - there was my mistake  - I've posted the wrong code for presenting popover. That's how it looks now..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757690/position-of-uipopovercontroller-in-ipad This question's answer may help you